# How can an Ethereum address start with 0x5555555555?

Tags: wallets, etherscan, addresses, cryptography

Ethereum wallet addresses start with 0x followed by random number and letters as a hexadecimal string. How is it possible then that there are addresses visible on Etherscan that seem to be "chosen", such as starting with "0x5555555555"?

Comment: Will link a question that I think answers this.  (For an EOA, similarly you can keep trying different private keys to see how your address looks.)

Comment: Thanks, but can't make any sense of the answer there. "vanity address" could mean anything. Here, the question is for fabricating a repetitive sequence of the same character within the wallet address itself. Like intentionally owning the phone number 1-888-8888

Comment: I think the process is the same. Imagine a very big bowl of numbers, and you want 888... You brute force, keep pulling out numbers from the bowl until you find what you want. With enough time and tries, you'll get an 8, then an 88, then an 888...

Comment: they couldn't have sat there trying manually. is there an automated approach?

Comment: The automated approach is what the code of vanity address generators do...